# Why isn't my properties file updated in my Web App project?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

I am trying to read and write a properties file with all my server and database connections in my JSF web application project in eclipse. Am using log4j to write to console. My config.properties file is:

```
dbserver=localhost
dbname=mydatabase;instance=myinstance
dbuser=myuser
dbpassword=mypassword
```

I placed my config.properties file in webapp/WEB-INF/classes folder (this is the classpath right?). I have verified that it is reading the file correctly in this specific location because if I delete the file, it breaks.

In my managed bean, I have functions to read and write to the config.properties file.

```
    public void getSettings() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(input);
        this.server = properties.getProperty("dbserver");
        this.db = properties.getProperty("dbname");
        this.user = properties.getProperty("dbuser");
        this.pass = properties.getProperty("dbpassword");
        logger.info("Config file successfully loaded!");            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Loading Database Settings Error with " + e);
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
                logger.info("Closing config file...");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error closing config file with " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void saveSettings() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        props.setProperty("dbserver", this.server);
        props.setProperty("dbname", this.db);
        props.setProperty("dbuser", this.user);
        props.setProperty("dbpassword", this.pass);
        URL url = classLoader.getResource("config.properties");
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File(url.toURI().getPath());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // File f = new File("config.properties");
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        props.store(out, "This is an optional header comment string");
        logger.info("Config file successfully saved!");
    } catch (IOException io) {
        logger.error("Saving configuration properties failed error with : " + io.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                logger.info("Closing config file...");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Failed closing configuration properties file error with : " + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I never had an issue reading from the properties file but had a hard time writing to the file. This issue seemed to have been solved by specifying

```
URL url = classLoader.getResource("config.properties");
```

Now, if I change the server name from "localhost" to "192.168.1.1", I can see that the new information persists even though I refresh the page or restart the server. HOWEVER... when I open the config.properties file, I still see

```
dbserver=localhost
```

when I am expecting to see

```
dbserver=192.168.1.1
```

The information seems to persist somewhere else even though the file still remains the same? How and where can I access the contents of my properties fie to see the changes that are being made to it?

Comment: JSF does not know anything about (re)loading properties files this way. So your question is not jsf related. _"I placed my config.properties file in webapp/WEB-INF/classes folder (this is the classpath right?). I "_ No, that is where it should end up. Most likely place is in a src folder (e.g. src/main/resources when using maven)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Am still trying to digest what you said but it did open my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the WAR file is a bad idea (for example, some web servers may notice the file modification an redeploy your app, there may be problems when the server explodes the war on deployment etc.)

I would suggest applying an alternative approach - some possibilities are:

Place the properties in a database table, so they can be easily modified

Use an external properties file for overriding your "Property.prop" file settings. You can pull this off for example as follows. Assume that the default property values are bundled in your WAR and the modified values are saved to some other path, which is defined using a system property - let say it's called CONFIG_LOCATION. Now after loading your properties from the bundle you read them also from this external "overrides.prop" file - this overrides your defaults from "Property.prop":

```
    PropertiesConfiguration pc1=new PropertiesConfiguration(a); 
    try(
FileReader propReader = new FileReader(System.getenv().get("CONFIG_FILES") +"/overrides.prop"){ pc1.load(propReader); 
}
```

When you need to save changes, you do that to "overrides.prop" - this will save all the properties, not only the changed ones, but that should have no negative effects.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. It has been a few days and am still wrapping my head around this paradigm. I had a hard time accepting that the only form of file persistence in Java EE is to save directly to the database...

Comment: @JoshuaTanton: It is nowhere stated that the only file persistence in Java EE is in a database. Where did you get this impression from?

Comment: @Kukeltje: To my limited understanding of JSF, there is absolutely no way of updating the values of a .properties or .xml configuration file? I even tried using apache commons configuration, but even though the value does seem to get updated, the value in my config file still remains the same even if I restart the server. Am I correct in thinking that the only way to be able to save dynamic configuration data is to use a database? Thank in advance!

Comment: @Kukeltje: Am I also correct in thinking that the only way I can edit a config properties file is to edit it manually (e.g. via text editor) before restarting the server? Thanks again in advance!